# gitolite repo is currupted after push

Tags: git, gitolite, gitweb

I'm trying to setup a gitolite server with gitweb as web interface. I've created a new user (named git) and installed gitolite as follows (git was installed previously):

```
git@server:~$ git clone git://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite
git@server:~$ mkdir /home/git/bin
git@server:~$ gitolite/install -ln
```

I've created a RSA key (gitolite_admin.pub) on my PC and uploaded it onto the the server and started the gitolite setup.

```
git@server:~$ bin/gitolite setup -pk gitolite_admin.pub
```

I can see the gitolite-admin repo in gitweb:
[image: before push]
After the setup on the server I've cloned the gitolite-admin.git repo onto my PC.

```
git clone ssh://git@server:6565/gitolite-admin.git
```

I edited gitolite-admin/conf/gitolite.conf like this:

```
repo gitolite-admin
    RW+     =   gitolite_admin

repo foo_repo
    RW+     =   gitolite_admin
```

commit + push

```
konze@desktop:gitolite-admin$ git commit -am "Added foo repo"
konze@desktop:gitolite-admin$ git push
```

After I've pushed the repo onto the server I can't see gitolite-admin.git in gitweb
[image]

The apache error log says this:

```
[Sun Sep 22 15:58:19 2013] index.cgi:  at /usr/share/gitweb/index.cgi line 2884
fatal: Not a git repository: '/home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git'
```

What went wrong? I can still access the git repos from my PC.

Comment: Just to be sure, try a re-do the installation, with an admin ssh key named "`gitolite`" or "`gitoliteadm`" instead of "gitolite-admin". Between the repo and the admin user, it is a bit confusing, and *could* cause the issue.

Comment: I've renamed `gitolite_admin.pub` to `gitolite.pub` and `gitoliteadm.pub` and installed it again, however it doesn't help.

Comment: Do you still see your `/home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git`? And what does your `/home/git/.gitolite/conf/gitolite.conf` file looks like?

Comment: Yes I do see `/home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git`. My `gitolite.conf` looks like the gitolite.conf in my first Post (after editing it on my PC).